# Import Articles & Blog posts reading list into Careers 2.0 from RSS

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I'm a heavy user of Instapaper and I would like to import my favorite articles into my Article & Blogs reading list.

Instapaper already publishes a RSS feed with my these articles, so everything I need from Careers 2.0 is to be able to import from RSS.

Comment: This is a feature request for Careers (that is, that Careers support importing RSS feeds).  It is therefore on-topic.  I'm not sure why it's garnered 2 off-topic votes.

Answer (score 3):

[GoodReads](http://www.goodreads.com) and/or [Shelfari](http://www.shelfari.com) integration to reading will be great feature addition.

Answer (score 0):

Goodreads was deemed "not suitable" according to this answer: [GoodReads integration?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173370/goodreads-integration/173373?s=3|0.6542#173373), but I would love goodreads import functionality as well. Goodreads already categorizes books based on Genre, maing it easy to scope the importing of books to:

- [Business](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/business)
- [Memoir?](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/memoir)
- [Psychology](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/psychology)
- [Science](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/science)
- [Economics](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/economics)
- [Game design](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/game-design)
- [Leadership](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/leadership)
- [Personal Development](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/personal-development)
- [Programming](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/programming)
- [Programming languages](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/programming-languages)
- [Internet](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/internet)
- [Web](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/web)
- [Web design](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/web-design)
- [Technical](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/technical)
- [Technology](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/technology)

I'd prefer it to be a One-off import a-la GitHub where the list of books not yet imported is shown and where I can then bulk-import them. Books skipped could be placed on a "not imported" list for future imports, but that would be "extra". being able to add "Science Fiction" as a category, because one wants to show off their Star-Wars Comic addiction may be a next step ;).

Importing from [Books24x7](http://www.books24x7.com/books24x7.asp) and [Safari Bookshelf](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/) would make sense from a reading public perspective as well.

I personally do **not** want to manually search and add books on multiple sites.

As a platform, Goodreads is a good match for StackExchange, being community driven, self-organizing and with a large group of volunteers that keep things tidy, called Librarians. Most of my IT friends are actively using Goodreads, I'd say at least 60% of 'm.