# GoodReads integration?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, books

I already track the books I'm reading on [GoodReads](http://www.goodreads.com/) and I'm much too lazy to look them up again.  What do folks think of an integration similar to github repos, where I'm prompted with a list of the books I've recently read, asked which I'd like to feature, and in what order?

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't understand the question here. What about GoodReads integration?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I'm guessing it's for StackOverflow Careers, under "add a book you've read"

Comment: @David Ahhh... that makes more sense.

Comment: Ouch.  Why all the downvotes?  The link at the bottom of careers says "Feedback always welcome" and links here.  I'm not feeling it...

Answer (score 3):

I assume that David Robinson is correct and you're suggesting that StackOverflow Careers integrate with GoodReads. Four reasons not to implement this feature are:

- It seems unlikely to have a widespread benefit. GoodReads looks like an interesting site, but I doubt that a significant number of people with SO Careers profiles use it. If it were desirable to integrate with some external book site, Amazon, B&N, and O'Reilly's Safari seem like better choices.
- Users who do use GoodReads will still likely want to tailor the list of books they present in their SO Careers profile. Yes, you could create a custom "shelf" in GoodReads, but at that point it's not much more work to simply create your list on SO Careers.
- Managing everything in your SO Careers profile inside the SO Careers interface is simple and reliable. Having to log into a separate site to manage your book list seems cumbersome.
- The current setup seems to be working pretty well.